# Lots of json files how to compile

Tags: json

It would be great if anyone had any suggestions of where i could start/what i could look at.

For the last few months I have been grabbing a json file everyday from twitter in the hope that at a later date I could play around with them using Processing. The issue i have is that i need all of these in one file rather that hundreds, so that's why I'm here. So i guess what I'm asking is whats the best way to compile lots of json files into one for easy access, or just an easy way to search all these files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can naively concatenate them using

```
for i in *.json; do
   cat $i >> /tmp/result
done
```

(using `bash` or similar). Of course you will likely need to prepend/suffix with a root node. Make sure you scrub `/tmp/result` if you want to run the above again.

A simpler variant would be `cat *.json > /tmp/result`

Answer (score 1):

For the mass-searching problem, you may want to look into the [json command-line tool](https://github.com/zpoley/json-command).